# ObjectQuery - what is it, how to get to it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am reading up on [Linq to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities#composing-the-queries).

[`ObjectQuery<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1?view=netframework-4.8) features prominently in these docs, but I don't quite understand what it is. From what I read, it is an object representing the query. I always thought that when I write a Linq query, I get an `IQueryable` out of it, so I can a) further compose it or b) enumerate it so it fetches data from the database.

1. How is `ObjectQuery` different from an `IQueryable`?
2. What is this 'command tree query' mentioned in the article? How is it different from an Expression Tree
3. Can I get to an `ObjectQuery` from the `IQueryable` I get when I write a Linq query?

Links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectquery-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Actually it's outdated, Once it was important, Before EF 5 this was the way to deal with queries, it's kept for Backward Compatibility, as well as ObjectContext. Don't start learning this, unless you have old code to maintain.

Comment: The article in question doesn't really point out the fact that this is an old way of doing things. They should've made it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of System.Data, something  separate from LINQ. Since it's converting an SQL-String to objects, it might be useful if for some reasons, you don't want to use LINQ or EF. The newer version in EF is

```
context.SqlQuery("Select * from Students").ToList<Student>();
```

would be the same as

```
new ObjectQuery<Student>("Select * from Students", context).
```

where the context in the latter is an Object Context and a DBContext in the first line. 
It's all not strongly typed and therefore 'simpler' or Quick & Dirty. Not the recommended way to go.

Recommended way is having a DbSet < Student> and not handle SQL Strings at all (if avoidable).

Comment: Does `ObjectQuery` have anything to do with Linq to Entities and EF 6?

Comment: as you see in the definition: `public class ObjectQuery<T> : System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.ComponentModel.IListSource, System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<T>, System.Linq.IQueryable<T>` it's part of it; and it is there since EF 1,2,3.
That started as  DataBase-First, involved EDMX-Files and generated code from inspecting the database. Today we rather use Code-First models. You write the Code manually and create the Database from it.
Probably we can consider an ObjectQuery as a LowLevel-Layer and maybe it's internally used by EF.